# How do i change an array of numbers into corresponding letters of the alphabet

Tags: bash

I have an array called `variable` that contains the numbers 1-26, i am trying to use a for loop in bash to go through each number of the array and associating it with a letter from the alphabet as `tr` only lets me translate the first few letters of the alphabet. An example of my code is

Note: i am using bash

```
#!/bin/bash
for p1 in "${variable[@]}"; do
    if (( $p1 == 1 )); then 
    newvar+='a'
    elif (( $p1 == 2 )); then
    newvar+='b'
    ...... and so on down to z
```

i am trying to create the string newvar which contains these translated letters. However when i try to run this it only shows me `a` which is the very first number translated. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Works fine here. Copy and paste your entire script to https://shellcheck.net and see if there is a problem

Comment: You should try to choose more descriptive variable names. `variable` doesn't sound like an array that holds numbers that map to letters. `newvar` has no meaning either.

Answer (score 2):

```
for p1 in "${variable[@]}"; do
  chars+=( $((p1 + 96)) )
done

printf '%b' $(printf '\\%03o' ${chars[@]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
# alphabet=(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)
alphabet=({a..z})

letters=(8 5 12 12 15 23 15 18 12 4)
phrase=''
for i in "${letters[@]}"; do
    phrase+="${alphabet[i-1]}"
done
echo $phrase
```

```
helloworld
```

Comment: Shorter alphabet declaration:  `alphabet=({a..z})`